# Unknown filesystem type on /dev/mapper/docker-202

Tags: ubuntu, docker, apt-get, dockerfile

I am attempting to build a docker image from Dockerfile. The file runs like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV HOME=/home/root
ENV GOPATH=$HOME/go
ENV PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin:$HOME/go/bin

RUN mkdir -p $HOME
RUN apt-get -y install wget
RUN apt-get -y install git
```

Everything works, until the installation of wget. It does appear to finish successfully but then, straight after `"Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d....done."` docker throws the following error:

```
INFO[0032] Unknown filesystem type on /dev/mapper/docker-202:1-145547-28276018...
```

The build then stops. I attempted to comment out the wget installation, but then the same thing happened upon git installation.
I then commented out the entire file, except the wget line, which WORKED, strangely enough. That obviously doesn't help me much, because the rest of the file is kind of important...
I then tried to see which line was the problematic one, but it seems that every single command executed before apt-get resulted in this failure straight after apt-get.

So I moved apt-get to the top of the file, and again, that WORKED, but the next command (`ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive`) resulted in the same failure. That's just plain weird...

Any ideas?

(Side note: when running a container from the ubuntu image and executing all the commands manually, everything works perfectly...)

**EDIT 22.07.15:** I neglected to mention this happens when running the build on an AWS EC2 instance (version 3.4.73-64.112.amzn1.x86_64). When I ran the exact same thing on a local virtual machine with Ubuntu 14.04, the build succeeded with no errors.

Comment: Weird. What about `docker build --no-cache .`?

Comment: Already running with --no-cache. My build command looks like this: `docker build --no-cache --rm -t repo/image:latest ~/somthing/src/docker/`

Comment: Your host has which OS and Linux version? By the way, wget is in UBUNTU:14.04, so you can try without the installation of wget

Comment: Updated the question to contain that information. I remember wget not being available by default, but either way, I do need to install git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I solved it. Sort of. I don't know why the problem was really caused (if someone does, please let me know, I'm curious), but here's how it was solved:
Instead of the device mapper filesystem, which seemed like the source of the problem, I created a btrfs filesystem, which docker appears to be quite happy with.

These are the steps I took:

I started by adding a new volume to my EC2 instance (2GB of General Purpose SSD). [This](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-add-volume-to-instance.html) is a really good guide for doing just that.

Now I started the switch from device mapper to btrfs:

```
sudo service docker stop
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker
sudo mkfs.btrfs -f -O ^extref -L docker /dev/xvdf # The extref option is not fully supported and causes all kinds of trouble, which is why I disabled it
sudo echo "/dev/xvdf /var/lib/docker btrfs defaults 0 0" >> /etc/fstab
sudo mount /dev/xvdf /mnt
```

Now I configured docker to use btrfs by editing the file `/etc/sysconfig/docker` like so:

```
Options="-s btrfs"
```

When I started the service (`sudo service docker start`), I could see, by running `docker info`, that the switch was successful: `Storage Driver: btrfs`.

I ran the build again, and it worked like a charm :)